# Checking whether input is a number or a character

Tags: swift2

I am trying a guessing game. Guessing between 0 and 5. I know most of my problems could be sorted using the numeric keypad for the data input, but I am trying to learn as much as I can, so I am trying to think of all the incorrect errors that could happen with a full keyboard and give the relevant err messages.

I think I have covered all, the only one I can´t get is giving an err when a character rather than a number is input. Can someone help. My code is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amyFd.png)

Thanks

Comment: You could try regular expressions. See http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you could make an array of numbers 1-5

```
let numbers: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Then you can check if the textfield input is valid

```
if textfieldname.text.count == 1 {
    if numbers.contains(textfieldname.text) {
        //do something
    } else { 
        //oops...
    }
else {
    //too many characters
}
```